# Grouping and adding values of grouped data. Problem with writing a query

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a csv file, I made a table from it in Access:

pastebin.com/pSVXsg5r

in the new table I would like to create four groups and assign them values.

- Group 1 EXP
- Group 2 KOM
- Group 3 PCK
- Group 4 **TRP**(new group name):HRL, L_F, LEA, PTP, SCH, TPE, UWA, VER.

[image]

I would like to display vdata1 vdata2 and HOURS for each user divided into groups. (sum of vdata1, sum of vdata2, sum of hours for each group EXP, KOM, PCK, TRP)

[image]

Here is my Database in Access, please hints or study materials

http://www.mediafire.com/file/dcska071cg4p2wh/Table.rar/file

Comment: That drive link requires password. I was able to download from the pastebin.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/dcska071cg4p2wh/Table.rar/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the group identifier and group on that field in aggregate query.

```
SELECT USERID, IIf([GRUPA] Not In ("EXP","KOM","PCK"),"TRP",[GRUPA]) AS GrpID, Sum(VDAT1) AS SumVDAT1, Sum(VDAT2) AS SumVDAT2, Sum(HOURS) AS SumHOURS
FROM Table
GROUP BY USERID, IIf([GRUPA] Not In ("EXP","KOM","PCK"),"TRP",[GRUPA]);
```

Or add another record to Groups:

> TRP TRP

Then join tables:

```
SELECT USERID, LGTYP, Sum(VDAT1) AS SumVDAT1, Sum(VDAT2) AS SumVDAT2, Sum(HOURS) AS SumHOURS
FROM Groups INNER JOIN Table ON Groups.GRUPA = Table.GRUPA
GROUP BY Table.USERID, Groups.LGTYP;
```

Comment: Take a look friend:
mediafire.com/file/dcska071cg4p2wh/Table.rar/file

Comment: I can't open rar files. You marked as answer. Is it working? I was able to extract from zip file posted on AccessForums. However, the Excel file was not provided so there is no data. I used the data in pastebin. The field you call LGTYP in that file I named GRUPA. See revised answer.